# lang-hs and lang-haskell color syntax differently

Tags: feature-request, bug, syntax-highlighting

### Bug

[The main answer on syntax coloring language selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/379373) says to use `lang-hs` for the Haskell programming language, but `lang-haskell` also exists, works differently, and parses incorrectly.

If nothing else, `lang-haskell`'s colorer should be thrown out and it should be made a synonym of `lang-hs`.

### Feature request

`lang-hs` seems to be the better parser of the two (see, for example, the correct detection of the comment surrounded by `{-` and `-}` in the first line), but it would be nice if:

- the cyan-colored parts (except for the part in the first line comment, obviously) of `lang-haskell` could be added to `lang-hs` to color type names such as `Integer` and module names such as `Example` and so forth.
- the reserved words `qualified` and `as` would be in dark blue in  "lines" (that is, the Haskell source code line can be split into multiple text file lines using indentation, so parsing correctly is a must) that start with `import`.

Could that be moved over and then `lang-haskell` be made a synonym of `lang-hs`?

### `lang-hs` example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Example (Integer2(Integer2), factorial) where
import qualified Data.List (transpose) as L

data IntegerWrapper = IntegerWrapper Integer
newtype Integer2 = Integer2 Integer

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = case n of
                   0 -> 1
                   x -> x*factorial (x - 1)
```

### `lang-haskell` example

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Example (Integer2(Integer2), factorial) where
import qualified Data.List (transpose) as L

data IntegerWrapper = IntegerWrapper Integer
newtype Integer2 = Integer2 Integer

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = case n of
                   0 -> 1
                   x -> x*factorial (x - 1)
```

Comment: `land-haskell` does *not* exist and it's reverting to default highlighting because it's invalid.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't expecting the default highlighting to highlight things like `module` and `where` properly, so I thought that it was Haskell-specific, but I see that you're correct.